# Image load when ajax call with javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

i want to add the loading image till i get ajax response, when click Onclick function in javascript. i using the function for ajax request as given below..where i fix loading image concept in below function...

```
function removeitem(product_id, msg) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('cartreturn').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementsByClassName('allitem').innerHTML = "Add";

        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/addcart.php?msg=" + msg, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Add the image in your function and remove it in `if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have commented section where you can place your image loading code

```
function removeitem(product_id, msg) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('cartreturn').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementsByClassName('allitem').innerHTML = "Add";
            //Code for removing loader
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/addcart.php?msg=" + msg, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    //Code for adding loader
}
```